# Is incriminating evidence in plain sight if a computer mouse had to be bumped to reveal it?

Tags: united-states, police, search-and-seizure

Let's say I have willingly invited the police into my living room.  Earlier I had been planning some highly illegal activities on my computer, located in the living room, and thus had incriminating evidence on the screen.  However, my computer is currently in hibernate mode, and so nothing is showing on the screen.  If anyone were to move the mouse, to wake my computer up, it would then display the evidence.  I'm wondering, if the computer were to be awaken, if the evidence could be deemed to be in plain sight.

I assume that if I was the one to accidentally bump my mouse, then yes, the evidence is in plain sight.  I also assume that if an officer walks over to my computer and, clearly and intentionally, moves the mouse to wake up the computer, that likely would not count as being in plain sight?

However, what if an officer claims to have accidentally bumped the mouse without intent?  Would the evidence on my computer then be in plain sight? What if they ask my minor son to show him the cool new wallpaper on the computer with the intent of getting the son to wake the computer so he can view its content?

Comment: so to clarify: you don't have taken even the basic step to have a password on the computer or the screen had just turned off but not the screen locked yet?

Comment: @Trish, so to clarify, your question has nothing to do with the legality of such a search, it's just a recommendation for anyone planning to do this?

Comment: @user6726 no, it's that windows since 8.0 actually *does* lock the screen with the basic setups and requires the password to re-log in. changing those settings does show certain knowledge about how to do it and a disregard for the own privacy, which might alter the conclusion.

Comment: @Trish you are correct that my current laptop does have a password on it, but for this question let's assume an older windows (or god forbid linux distro!) that doesn't mandate a password.  Just waking the computer is enough to view the screen

Comment: I would be stunned if any court held that deliberate snooping on a computer without a warrant is rendered reasonable if the owner "negligently" failed to apply extreme security measures, such as encrypting the drive.

Comment: I suspect that this would be resolved as a question of fact by the trial court and overturned on appeal only if the decision was determined to be an abuse of discretion,  which it would not if the reasoning was well articulated, even if this made inconsistent resolution of seemingly similar situations possible.

Comment: As a starter, suppose it was stipulated by both sides that (a) the officer deliberately bumped the mouse or (b) the officer intentionally asked the child to bump the mouse to make the screen contents be in plain sight. Is this still a matter of fact and not law?

Comment: @user6726 Context always matters and even when the facts are not in dispute the reasonable inferences that can be drawn from them can differ.

Comment: @user6726 It's safe to say that if the officer deliberately bumped the mouse, the evidence on the computer screen would be inadmissible in court. SCOTUS has long refused to allow cursory inspections of items which are nonetheless in plain view. For example, speakers in plain view, but having to look at their bottoms for the serial numbers; notebooks on a desk being opened; VHS tapes in a player and pressing 'play,' have all been deemed improper. If probable cause that something is evidence of a crime can't be established without further intrusion, no matter how slight, seizure is unjustified.

Comment: @A.fm. that's a good point, and if you elaborated on it with some more details and links to relevant cases it would likely make a better answer then the currently selected one and get chosen in it's place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is such a fact specific question that I doubt there's a precedent that covers it exactly. It could probably go either way.